# Android TextView and ImageView not updating until the end of loop

Tags: android, textview, imageview

So I'm fairly sure I'm using them correctly but for some reason I'm only getting the last update.

```
for(int i=0; i<numImages; i++)
{
    // Stuff processes here including getting a new Bitmap bmp image
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    text.setText(text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");
    Log.d("update", text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");
}
```

The log messages are showing as expected but I only see the final text update and final image in the sequence. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Iterating loop and displaying image in only ImageView? What do you want exactly?

Comment: Do you want to show some kind of animation? are you trying to do it every certain amount of time?. your code is overriding the last bmp and text set each time the loop runs again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the same `ImageView: imageView` and same `TextView: text`, only the last Bitmap and Text will be seen.

Are you trying to add all of the Bitmaps and respective text to the Layout??

**Do something like:**

```
for(int i=0; i<numImages; i++)
{
// Stuff processes here including getting a new Bitmap bmp image
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
parent.addView(imageView);

TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText(text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");
parent.addView(text);
Log.d("update", text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");
}
```

If you want to add a Bitmap to the ImageView every few seconds:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private TimerTask timerTask;
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
 public void run() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
         //Keep a count and change the ImageView and Text depending on that count
        }
});   
 }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: Well I have a bunch of images that are being loaded from a file. Some processing is being done on them. I want to be able to display 1 and the text, ideally have a pause, then display the next, and so on until the end of the loop

Comment: Then use a Timer and run the loop every 2 secs or so.

Comment: I actually tried this and a CalledFromWrongThread exception stating only the thread that created the view hierarchy can touch its view

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a buffer, then append your string to buffer everytime. then finally display it
EXAMPLE

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

for(int i=0; i<numImages; i++)
{
    // Stuff processes here including getting a new Bitmap bmp image
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    buff.append (text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");
}
Log.d(buff.toString());
```

Comment: Well I don't want it all to display at the end. I want the text to display at every iteration. The processing usually takes on the order of seconds so I should be able to see each image/text in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered such problems when I want to update my listview.
My log shows that several notifyDataSetChanged() was successfully executed but only the last call changed the listview, and it turns out that I put my computation in the main thread, which blocked the UI operation.

So, make sure your code is running in a individual thread, only do UI related operation in the main thread. You can try to all your code in a new Thread and put 
    `text.setText(text.getText()+"image "+i+" a success!\n");` in runOnUiThread